# InfoPath using SharePointListUrl() as Content Type

Tags: sharepoint, infopath, contenttype

I am using InfoPath 2010 and publish my form to a document library.  On my form (that is emailed to the user) I generate a link that takes the user back to the list item so they can quickly return to the item for approvals or editing.  The link is generated like so:

```
concat(SharePointSiteUrl(), "_layouts/FormServer.aspx
?XmlLocation=", SharePointListUrl(), fileName, ".xml
&ClientInstalled=true
&Source=", SharePointListUrl(), "Forms/AllItems.aspx
&DefaultItemOpen=1")
```

and generates a valid URL like:

```
http://sharepoint/sites/mysite/_layouts/FormServer.aspx?XmlLocation=/sites/mysite/Office%20Resource/2012-10-03-6.xml&ClientInstalled=true&Source=http://sharepoint/sites/mysite/Office%2520Resource%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1
```

When I published this site as a CONTENT TYPE this link no longer worked.  When I viewed the output of the link that was generated, it appeared that the built in function **SharePointListUrl()** no longer returned anything.  I have to assume that this will not work with Content Types but I have found no reference to this being fact.  My work around has been to simply hard code in the missing values.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just paste your SharePointSiteURL() into a form field and promote that field to the list.  Then you can just use the promoted field that contains your URL to build your email via workflow?